# Is a platform mandatory for cuDNN?

Tags: c++, cuda, cudnn

I am using Cuda in C++ for some time now and I would like to try cuDNN. I would like to go straight in C++ but I can mostly only find examples and tutorials that are based on different platforms like Caffè or TensorFlow. Does it mean that I cannot use cuDNN in plain C++?
I need to have the highest possible performance.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use cuDNN in plain C++.

As a library, it is targeted at Deep Neural Networks/Deep Learning, so many DL Frameworks use it for acceleration of their workloads.

But there is nothing that prevents you from using the library directly, and there should be sufficient API level documentation for you to do so.

If you're unfamiliar with some of the concepts (e.g. tensors), you may find the library more difficult to comprehend, so certainly general familiarity with current common DL concepts will be beneficial in understanding how to use it.

Comment: Thank you Robert. From your experience, does it make sense to go for plain C++? Will it be faster than the rest?

Comment: The question is not sensible, IMO.  Frameworks such as caffe, theano, torch, tensorflow, and others, are there to provide an environment more comfortable for a DL researcher/developer.  They provide a high level of abstraction.  cuDNN is a lower level acceleration library.

Comment: What I meant is that I am going to code neural networks and before choosing a platform (or no platform), I need advices regarding performance. Seeing that most of them use Python makes me believe that simulations will run slower than plain C++. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: We're not going to be able to sort this out in the comments.  You're effectively asking for a tutorial on neural network framework design.  These are not simple questions.  A framework like tensorflow may use python at a high level, but if you study the tensorflow source code, a good deal of it is written in C++ for speed.  You're looking at a bunch of skyscrapers and trying to decide if you should just use one of those, or build your own.  If you can build a better skyscraper, go ahead.  But don't underestimate the work involved.  Your first question was one I can answer.  These are not.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for your help Robert